# adding 2nd group level in CollectionViewSource -> exception: Unable to cast object of type MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal to type

Tags: c#, wpf

When trying to add a second grouping level in a WPF CollectionViewSource, I get the error Unable to cast object of type 'MS.Internal.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal' to type 'MyApp.ContractEx'.

```
<CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
      <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="ThisNewGroupCausesException"/>
      <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="Month"/>
</CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
```

There is no additional debug information since the debugger does not stop on the line that causes the break.

```
public class MyConverter: IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var list = value as IEnumerable<object>;
        if (list == null)
            return "0";// "$0.00";

        int sumX =0, sumY=0;
        foreach (var Cn in list) if (Cn != null)
            {
                ContractEx C = (ContractEx)Cn; //casting so we can access the properties in the code below.
                sumX += C.Ammount;
                sumY += C.Height;
            }
        return sumX + " / " + sumY;
    } 
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research, I zeroed in on the Converter as the point of failure.
The exception occurrs inside the `IValueConverter`

The cast below (from the above converter) assumes the list contains objects of type ContractEx, which was the case, before adding the new group level.

```
foreach (var Cn in list) if (Cn != null)
        {
            ContractEx C = (ContractEx)Cn;
```

After adding a second group level, the list provided to the converter is no longer a list of ContractEx. Instead it is a list of type CollectionViewGroupInternal, each of its instances contains a list of ContractEx called items. This additional level of nesting is a direct result of the additional Group level.
**Updating the code to account for this nesting (as follows) solves the problem:**

```
foreach (CollectionViewGroup cvg in list)
            foreach (var Cn in cvg.Items) if (Cn != null)
```

Note that CollectionViewGroupInternal mentioned in the exception is no accessible, but CollectionViewGroup is.